# How to make a StopExecutingWhenYouHaveAResultAndReturnThatResult monad

Tags: c#, linq, monads

I have a special need for a kind of reverse Maybe monad that when being "Nothing" will continue to try to get a value and will keep the first valid value that it gets.

I have tried to outline what I mean here:

```
public void Test()
{
    var r = from x in SomeActionToGetResult()
            from y in Stop()
            from z in SomeOtherActionToGetResult()
            select x | y | z;
}

public Maybe<Result> SomeActionToGetResult()
{
    return new Result().Unit();
}

public Maybe<Result> SomeOtherActionToGetResult()
{
    return new Result().Unit();
}

public Maybe<Result> Stop()
{
    return new Nothing<Result>();
}
```

The Result class looks like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public static Result operator |(Result a, Result b)
    {
        if (a != null)
            return a;

        return b;
    }
}
```

The Unit function is like normal, but the Bind functions gives me trouble:

```
public static Maybe<U> Bind<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k)
{
    if (!m.HasAValidValue)
        return k(m.Value);

    return m; // <--- problem right here
}
```

As can be seen, I will - given that `m` has no value - try to run `k()` to obtain a valid value. If `m` already has a value I will like to use that and never run `k()`.

T and U start out as the same type - but as soon as the anonymous types in the linq query kicks in, I can no longer rely on that.

Is this at all possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This *may* not be any help to you, in which case I'll just delete it. If you're playing around with monads this is quite possibly teaching my grandmother to suck eggs, but...)

Are you aware that C# already has this at a language level with the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)?

```
var r = SomeActionToGetResult() ?? Stop() ?? SomeOtherActionToGetResult();
```

If you need to achieve this in a more library-based form, that's fine (and I'll see what I can think of) but if you *can* just use the existing operator, I would.

EDIT: I've had a go at your puzzle, and I think basically it's not a good fit for LINQ. The problems are mostly to do with the types that LINQ expects in `SelectMany`. For example, your second line is effectively transformed to:

```
SomeActionToGetResult().SelectMany(x => Stop(), (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

Here the problems are:

- We *don't* use the value of `x` in the `Stop()` expression, and logically *can't* as we only want it to be executed if `x` evaluates to `None`
- The anonymous type is necessarily not the same type as the `T` part of the return type of `SomeActionToGetResult()`, so we can't convert it into a `Maybe<T>`. We'd have to introduce a new type to extract them both.

Then later when we have:

```
select x | y | z
```

Is that logically the *only* thing you could have? Would it make sense to have

```
select z | y | x
```

and if so, what would that mean? We *can't* avoid `SomeActionToGetResult()` from being executed to start with, as the extension method only works on the result of that method call... so either the projection has to be ignored and you always evaluate `x`, then `y`, then `z` - or you accept that the ordering won't always be preserved exactly.

Fundamentally I suspect you haven't *really* got a monad here, otherwise I'd expect it to fit - but I'm not really competent enough in the maths to say.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm aware of the null-coalescing operator, and I actually could use it, I guess, but returning null from a method to signal "stop processing" seems a little blurry, and I just wanted to make it clearer. My "Maybe" will in my program be named "StopOr", just called it Maybe here for familiarity :) ... I've been hitting this problem a lot lately, and now I began to wonder if it is possible at all to make it as clear as I want it.

Comment: Another case I had where I hit this problem - where the null-coalescing operator was not usable - was when the monad was carrying more than one value to determine it's behavior.

Comment: @asgerhallas: You could use a `Tuple<,,,>` in that case... I can look at implementing appropriate `SelectMany` (etc) calls for this sort of thing - I'll see what I can do this evening. No promises though...

Comment: Oh, that would be very nice indeed! :)

Comment: @asgerhallas: Have edited, but I don't think you'll like my conclusion :(

Comment: But I really appreciate the effort! I'm still learning this, and guess you're right, when you say it might not even be a monad to begin with. I just thought it looked so like it :) ... one thing, when you say "We'd have to introduce a new type to extract them both", I'm not quite sure what do you mean, if you could actually do that or if it's what should be done in a hypothetical other language that supported it? Again thank you very much.

Comment: @asgerhallas: Um, I'm not entirely sure on the new type bit, to be honest. It's not clear to me whether it's even slightly possible within C#...